# Combining 2 streams with a subscribe operation for each

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this following code which do the same operation but for two different ID :

This section is for retrieving my thread object :

```
this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    map(params => this.threadId = params.get('threadId')),
    switchMap(threadId => this.threadsStoreService.threads
      .pipe(map(threads => threads.find(threadItem => threadItem._id === threadId))))
  )
  .subscribe(thread => this.thread = thread);
```

and this section is for retrieving my message object :

```
this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    map(params => this.messageId = params.get('messageId')),
    switchMap(messageId => this.messagesStoreService.messages
      .pipe(map(messages => messages.find(messageItem => messageItem._id === messageId))))
  )
  .subscribe(message => this.message = message);
```

Because I need to subscribe to each stream to retrieve the objects (thread and message) I am wondering if there is a way to combining these streams together?
I tried with `forkJoin` with no success.

Thanks in advance for you answer.

Comment: You want to combine them how? What didn't work with `forkJoin`?

Comment: So is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider to use the `tap` operator (formerly known as `do`).

`tap` allows you to add an Observer wherever you want in the pipe chain.

So in you  case you could have something like

favorite

I have this following code which do the same operation but for two different ID :

This section is for retrieving my thread object :

```
const thread$ = this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    map(params => this.threadId = params.get('threadId')),
    switchMap(threadId => this.threadsStoreService.threads
      .pipe(map(threads => threads.find(threadItem => threadItem._id === threadId)))),
    tap(thread => this.thread = thread)
  );

const message$ = this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    map(params => this.messageId = params.get('messageId')),
    switchMap(messageId => this.messagesStoreService.messages
      .pipe(map(messages => messages.find(messageItem => messageItem._id === messageId)))),
    tap(message => this.message = message)
  );

merge(thread$, message$).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your data into an array, and get the thread and message. In this example, you have to fill the types of "thread" and "message".

```
type SubscriptionOutputTypes = [<insert thread type here> , <insert message type here>];
this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    map(params => {
      this.threadId = params.get('threadId');
      this.messageId = params.get('messageId')
    }),
    switchMap( _ =>
              zip(
                this.threadsStoreService.threads.pipe(map(threads => threads.find(threadItem => threadItem._id === this.threadId)))
                ,
                this.messagesStoreService.messages.pipe(map(messages => messages.find(messageItem => messageItem._id === this.messageId)))
              )
             )
  )
  .subscribe( ([thread, message] : SubscriptionOutputTypes) => {
    this.thread = thread;
    this.message = message;
  });
```